# Using parameters passed through react navigation in functions

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

### **Problem**

I'm trying to use parameters I pass with react navigation in react native inside of functions. I define the parameters like this:

```
render() {
  const { params } = this.props.navigation.state; 
  return (
```

And whenever I try to use a parameter in a function, for example `params.userID` I get an error saying, "can't find variable params". When I try to use

```
this.setState({passUserID: this.props.navigation.state.userID})
```

that just returns null. I would pass the parameters into the function, but I call functions from within other functions. The impractical solution I have been using is making a user press a button that defines a bunch of states with all of the parameters in them:

```
<Button
    onPress={() =>{
    this.setState({passKey: params.postKey})
    this.setState({passUserID: params.userID})
    this.setState({passContent: params.postContent})
    this.setState({firebaseItems:''});
    this.setState({fontLoaded:true});
    }}
    title="Press to load"
    color="#ff0037"
  />
```

But this is impractical for the user, because each time they want to load this screen they have to press a button.

So how can I use params inside of functions, or what other solutions can I try?

**Code**

```
class Feed extends React.Component {
        //...
        //Where I send the parameters and navigate to the other screen
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
     this.props.navigation.navigate(
    'CommentScreen',{postKey: item.key, postContent: item.content, passNameID: item.nameID, userID: item.userID}
    )
        }}>
        //...
                        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        //...

And then later:

        class Comments extends React.Component {
    //...

    render() {
    //where I receive the parameters
      const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;

      return (

//...
//How I use parameters
    <Text>
      {params && params.postContent}
    </Text>
```

Comment: Could you provide the full code where you pass params and where you receive those params?

Comment: @HuyVo I added the code under the code section.

Comment: @GllSE also how you use `params` under `return()`, it's the most important part.

Comment: @HuyVo I added it now.

Answer (score 0):

`params` is declared in `render()`. If you want to use the values in another function, you can use `this.props.navigation.state`.

Note: when you want to set several state values, you can do it all in one call to `this.setState()`:

```
this.setState({
    passKey: params.postKey,
    passUserID: params.userID,
    passContent: params.postContent,
    firebaseItems:'',
    fontLoaded:true
});
```